# JQuery How to traverse to <form> from <button> with descendant between

Tags: jquery, forms, button, traversal, descendant

I want to know, in JQuery, how to get the from the selector `$('button')` to the `<form>` element, without using id?
I know how to use id to get it, but somehow I need the method above.

I tried `alert($('button').parent().prev().get(0).nodeName)` it popups `FORM` that means I got there. But when I use `$('button').parent().prev().get(0).submit()` or `.serialize()` or even `.attr('name')`, it doesn't work.

The structure is as below, I have 10 rows of `<tr>......</tr>`.

```
<table>
    <tr><form name='form' method='POST' autocomplete='on'>
    <td id='df'><button type='button'>Go</button></td>
    <td><input type='reset' value='Clear'/></td>
    <td><input name='date'</td>
    <td><input name='customer'</td>
    .......
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any expert on traversing could teach me?? Thank you =)

Comment: `$(...).closest('form')` but I think your HTML is invalid: you cannot have a `form` sliced between a `tr` and `td` so it boils down to what the DOM _actually_ is.

Comment: ^ What @JanDvorak said; your HTML is definitely not valid. Move the `<form>` declaration before the `<table>` and close it after the table. Or if you need one form per row, you'll have to re-think the layout; you may not be able to use a `<table>` efficiently (you may need multiple tables, or `<div>`-only-based-approach.

Comment: Yes form has to be outside of the table otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Have to be outside <table>, not even before <tr>?

Comment: YES YOU GUYS ARE RIGHT. SO I HAVE TO USE <DIV>. THANKS EVERYONE! IT'S A GOOD PLACE TO LEARN!

Answer (score 0):

You have this HTML:

```
<table>
<tr><form name='form' method='POST' autocomplete='on'>
<td id='df'><button type='button'>Go</button></td>
.......
</tr>
</table>
```

This is what you think it will produce:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>
        <button/>
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then `$(...).closest('form')` is probably the desired traversal method.

This is what Google Chrome produces; it treats the form as a row caption ( http://jsfiddle.net/UULtc/ ):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <form/>
    <td>
      <button/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can access the form as `$(...).closest('tr').find('form:first')` but the form won't contain its intended inputs anyways, so beware.

You need to change your HTML (if there's only one row, simply wrap the form around the table). If you are going to stick to tables, you likely need to change the javascript as well. This is an idea (unpolished, untested):

```
$('table button').click(function(){
  $(this)
    .closest('table')
    .find('tr')
    .not($(this).closest('tr'))
    .find('input')
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
  ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change your html to this one and  then try.

```
<form name='form' method='POST' autocomplete='on'>
<table>
    <tr>
       <td id='df'><button type='button'>Go</button></td>
       <td><input type='reset' value='Clear'/></td>
       <td><input name='date'</td>
       <td><input name='customer'</td>
    .......
   </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm afraid OP needs/wants one form per row.

Comment: than try to use table in to another table

Answer (score 0):

I think i'ts because the `.get()` method returns a node, so you can not call a jQuery method on it, like `.submit()` or `.attr()`.

Since you only get one element, I dont think you need to use the `.get()` method before submitting or getting the name attribute.

`$('button').parent().prev().attr('name')` actually gives me your form's name.

Comment: It gives "undefined", so i guess .serialize() wouldn't work properly?